# Ports & processes

Tags: http, networking, tcp

Is the port number unique per process? Is it the relation 1:1 If no how does the system know to with process to deliver the response?

Answer (score 1):

Operating system identifies TCP connection end point with 4 parameters:

**local port, local address, remote port, remote address**

So local port does not need to be unique. It is usually unique for listening (i.e. server) sockets, because listening sockets usually have remote port and remote address unbound. But even for listening sockets, if a machine has multiple IP addresses you can have one process listening on a given port and one IP address and some other process listening on the same port but different IP address.

For connected sockets, the all 4 values are bound, because of this the same local port can be used by many simultaneous connections. Thanks to this, the number of open connections on a single machine is not limited to 64K, which would be pretty restrictive.

Answer (score 0):

The port number is unique per system: two processes cannot [re]open the same port number.